# Plotting a Matrix in 3D space in MATLAB without using mesh and surf type of plots

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

I am not familiar with MATLAB environment and I want to draw a matrix in a way that presents **each cell of a matrix** as **a point** in the 3D space.

For example present matrix "A " with the following  points in 3D space:
x=1, y=1 Z= 10 , x=1, y=3 Z=27 until reach the point x=3, y=3, z=26.

```
 A =
    10    15    27
    56    87     2
    90    87    26
```

I do not want to use mesh and surf. I am looking for diagram like plot3 digram.I tried plot3 but it does not show the value of z  correctly.

```
i=1:3;
j=1:3;
plot3(i,j,A(i,j))
```

[image]

In the above figure; 3 values are presented for when  x=3 and y=3 however it should present these values for x=1,y=3; x=2,y=3;x=3,y=3

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of result you're looking for. Maybe [scatter3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html)? What do you mean by "does not show the value of z correctly"?

Comment: @beaker I add figure to explain the * *does not show the value of z correctly* *. How should I write a command scatter3 to presents all points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin I would recommend you to change your variable names. I'll use `x` and `y` instead of `i` and `j`. In many language these symbols are more typically used for scalar index rather than full vector indices, and in Matlab they can have a special significance (*they are used to represent complex numbers*).

That said, in your statement `i=1:3;` you only generate 3 indices, but you have 9 values to plot in your matrix. These 3 indices have to be repeated (3 times in your case, one for each column). So a proper `x` and `y` generation would be:

```
%% // Manual mesh/coordinate generation
x = bsxfun(@times,1:size(A,1), ones([size(A,2) 1])) ;
x = x(:) ;

y = bsxfun(@times, ones([1 size(A,1)]) , (1:size(A,2)).' )  ;
y = y(:) ;
```

With that you can use at your convenience `scatter3` or `plot3`:

```
hscat = scatter3( x, y, A(:) ) ;
hp3 = plot3( x, y, A(:),'Marker','o','LineStyle','none') ;
%// will both produce exactly the same result
```

---

Now please consider the fact that the way I generated the `x` and `y` coordinate is nothing more than what `meshgrid` would do for you (or the more dimension generic `ndgrid`).

For example, in the code below, the 3 plotting methods will produce exactly the same ouput than above, so just take your pick:

```
%% define a grid
[X,Y] = meshgrid( 1:size(A,1) , 1:size(A,2) ) ;

%% // surface plot (but only points visible, no line)
hsurf = surf(X,Y,A,'Marker','o','LineStyle','none','FaceColor','none') ;

%% // scatter3
hscat = scatter3( X(:), Y(:), A(:) ) ;

%% // plot3
hp3 = plot3( X(:), Y(:), A(:),'Marker','o','LineStyle','none') ;
```

Why reinvent the wheel when you have one at hand ... `meshgrid` do the job for you in less code instruction ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To generate the coordinates, you should use [ndgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) (or [meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), which swaps `X` and `Y`.):

```
[X, Y] = ndgrid(1:3, 1:3);
```

`plot3` is going to connect the input points with a line, so if you want distinct points in your plot, use [scatter3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html):

```
scatter3(X(:), Y(:), A(:));
```

(You can also use `plot3` in the same way if you want the lines.)

Comment: Your command does not create what I want. It creates 2 dimensions plot.

Comment: I don't see how, if I'm passing 3 different coordinate vectors 2 a 3-dimensional scatter plot.

Comment: By the way, Hoki's answer is much more complete than mine, but his `meshgrid/scatter3` solution at the end is pretty much identical.